# element.remove() not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, dom

When I write this code it says

> Cannot read property 'remove' of null

```
var tileWrapper=document.querySelector(".tile[data-id='"+tileId+"']");
tileWrapper.remove();
```

But following works fine

```
var tileWrapper=document.querySelector(".tile[data-id='"+tileId+"']");
setTimeout(function () {tileWrapper.remove();},200);
```

Comment: But in fiddle or codepan it works fine

Comment: .remove() is from jquery you need the correct syntax do both work on fiddle??

Comment: but it removes the element

Comment: the problem is it is displaying the error

Comment: is your `titleWrapper.remove()` work on fiddle

Comment: when you step through does `titleWrapper` have a value?

Comment: yes it works,
[Codepan](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOjGzE)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83615/discussion-between-amit-saharan-and-josh-stevens).